# c# allow duplicate in list.add

Tags: c#, collections, nhibernate

i have trouble in adding duplicate element to a list

i want to add that object:

```
public class Allegato : BaseObject<Allegato, int>
    {
        public override int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string NomeFile { get; set; }
    }
```

in BaseObject i implement equals looking only at Id Field

i cannot change this settings since those is need to my NHibernate Data Access Infrastracture

now i have other class with a list of `Allegato` objects

```
public class Corso : BaseObject<Corso, int>
{
public virtual ICollection<Allegato> Allegati { get; set; } = new List<Allegato>();

        public virtual void AddAllegato(Allegato allegato)
        {
            this.Allegati.Add(allegato);
        }
}
```

Now i need to add many Allegato to collection and then save it to database, ID will be empty since will be generate by DB sequence

```
using (myUow = myUowFactory.Create())
        {
            var obj = new Corso();
            //populate corso
            myUow.Corsi.Create(obj);
            
            var files = SessionManagement.LeggiOggetto<SessionObject.File>(HttpContext, SessionManagement.ChiaveSessione.File);
            foreach (var file in files)
                obj.AddAllegato(new Allegato { NomeFile = file.Nome });

            myUow.SaveAll();
        }
```

**first object is added but all other no. first element remain all others are not added
debugging it see that `equals` method of `Allegato` class is called, how can i avoid it?**

thanks

EDIT

base object class

```
public abstract class BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> : EquatableObject<TEntity>
where TEntity : class
{
    public abstract TKey Id { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> other = obj as BaseObject<TEntity, TKey>;

        return BaseObjectEquals(other);

    }

    public override bool Equals(TEntity obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> other = obj as BaseObject<TEntity, TKey>;

        return BaseObjectEquals(other);

    }

    public virtual bool BaseObjectEquals(BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(this.Id , other.Id);
    }

    private IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetFields()
    {
        Type t = GetType();

        List<FieldInfo> fields = new List<FieldInfo>();
        while (t != typeof(object))
        {
            fields.AddRange(t.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredFields.Where(x => x.FieldType.Name != typeof(ICollection<>).Name));//.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public));

            t = t.GetTypeInfo().BaseType;
        }
        return fields;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> x, BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> y)
    {
        // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
        if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // If one is null, but not both, return false.
        if (((object)x == null) || ((object)y == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> x, BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> y)
    {
        return !(x == y);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing stopping you adding in duplicate items here, and since you haven't shown the full code, there's not really much we can do to help here. We have no idea what BaseObject is or how it works, we have no idea how your UoW class works or how things are added to the database.

Comment: problem is not in database but in class code: this.Allegati.Add(allegato); does not add new values to the collection, only the first

Comment: If you were talking about `HashSet` or a `Dictionary`'s keys, it would make sense, but the `List` class has *no feature* for preventing duplicates (based on Equals, reference equality, or anything else) during `Add`.

Comment: i debug it three times: after second call this.Allegati contains only one element and a call to Equals of BAseObject is done during Add method

Comment: What is `EquatableObject<T>`? Either way, there's still no code that prevents you adding multiple items to a `List<T>`. You need to give us a [mre]

Comment: Read the code for [`Add`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,220). The only thing it does with the passed in `item` is place it in the backing array.

Comment: @gt.guybrush `System.Collections.Generric.List<T>` allows duplicates. That's not up to discussion.  `public virtual ICollection<Allegato> Allegati` on the other hand is **not** a `List<T>`, even if its original value was a `List<T>`. NHiberrnate will replace it with its own implementation to allow for lazy loading. *That* implementation won't allow entries with identical primary keys because that's clearly invalid

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos thanks, so i have to find a way to add multiple elements and save it once. i don't want to make a roundtrip to database for every item

Comment: `ID will be empty` in that case, NHibernate will insert all items and let the database generate the keys *if it's configured correctly*. If that doesn't happen, you have a problem with NHibernate's configuration. How *do* you configure `Id`? `Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();` should work. If you use XML, `<id name="Id" ...generator="identity" `

Comment: it's Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.SeqHiLo("SEQ_GSA_014", "1");

Comment: and Allegato map in corso HasManyToMany(x => x.Allegati)
    .Table("NAV_GSA_ALL_CORSO_015")
    .ParentKeyColumn("ID_CORSO_015_KNUM")
    .ChildKeyColumn("ID_ALLEGATO_015_KNUM")
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .AsSet();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as  @Panagiotis Kanavos stated, problem is in NHibernate overwrite of my property with a Set collection. I changed the map to Bag to make it work